# invalid field found for struct while automigrating

Tags: postgresql, go, grails-orm, go-gorm

I am gettin this error when i try to automigrate my tables based on my structs i dont know why im gettin this error

> failed to parse value &models.Model{ID:0x0, CreatedAt:time.Date(1,
> time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), UpdatedAt:time.Date(1,
> time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), DeletedAt:,
> DogData:[]models.DogData(nil)}, got error invalid field found for
> struct github.com/dog-page/models.Model's field DogData: define a
> valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner
> interface

im new at golang languague and gorm specificly when it comes to create struct for raw json data here are my intention of a struct using gorm:

```go
type Model struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primarykey:id" json:"id:_id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time  `gorm:"column:created_at" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time  `gorm:"column:updated_at" json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `gorm:"column:deleted_at" json:"deleted_at"`
    DogData   []DogData
}

type DogData struct {
    DogDataID    uint
    Name         string         `json:"name"`
    Life_Span    string         `json:"life_span"`
    Temperaments string         `json:"temperament"`
    Weight       datatypes.JSON `json:"weight"`
    Height       datatypes.JSON `json:"height"`
    Image        datatypes.JSON `json:"image"`
}

type Weight struct {
    Imperial string `json:"imperial"`
    Metric   string `json:"metric"`
}

type Height struct {
    Imperial string `json:"imperial"`
    Metric   string `json:"metric"`
}

type Image struct {
    URL string `json:"url"`
}
```

Comment: let me know if you need a picture for this answer or more information thanks for the help on advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Model's field DogData: define a valid foreign key for relations

Model has [one-to-many](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key) relation to DogData, for which gorm is not able to identify the foreign key.

You need to specify the column that will store `Model.ID` in `DogData` (gorm looks for ModelID by default),

```go
type Model struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primarykey:id" json:"id:_id"`
...
    DogData []DogData
}

type DogData struct {
    ModelID      uint
    DogDataID    uint
...
}
//CREATE TABLE `dog_data` (`model_id` integer,`dog_data_id` integer,`name` text,`life_span` text,`temperaments` text,CONSTRAINT `fk_models_dog_data` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES `models`(`id`))
```

OR if you want to use another column than specify that with foreignKey tag

```go
type Model struct {
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primarykey:id" json:"id:_id"`
...
    DogData   []DogData  `gorm:"foreignKey:DogDataID"`

}

type DogData struct {
    DogDataID    uint
...
}

//CREATE TABLE `dog_data` (`model_id` integer,`dog_data_id` integer,`name` text,`life_span` text,`temperaments` text,CONSTRAINT `fk_models_dog_data` FOREIGN KEY (`dog_data_id`) REFERENCES `models`(`id`))
```

Not sure about the use case but I think the `DogData` can be simplified as, dropping `Model` struct completely as it is same as `gorm.Model`

```go
type DogData struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name         string         `json:"name"`
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer now is working but i got a problem every time that i try to unmarshall the information i was gettin bunch of 0, i figure it out why, and it was cause i was treating at my model DogData as it where a normal object but inside the endpoint response it comes like a nested array with objects inside

Comment: so y try to use type DogData []struct {} and everything else.. and its unmarshalling but now the terminal is throwing me another error related to this: ERROR: syntax error at or near "dog_data_id" (SQLSTATE 42601) seems like postgres is not acepting  the DogData []struct expression but idk how to change it in order for it to accepted

Comment: nevermind i fixed it already it was the way that i was declaring the model since it is an array first i had to declared as it was var dogs []models.DogData another new think learned